# How do I display particular images and links based on the logic in a form?

Tags: forms, logic

I searched for this but I couldn't find anything.

I want to display a particular image and link based on the answers in a form.

For example if someone answers "Yes" for a question, after clicking on the submit button. He/She should be seeing image1 and link1 and if someone answers "No" then they should be seeing image2 and link2.

Similarly, the logic of showing images and link can be based on combination of answers. Like first answer "Yes" + second answer "No" = image3 and link3

Note: The images and links must be displayed after final form submission.

Thanks!
Regards,
Edward

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the language you use to implement, you could have a map from N answers to the index of image and link to display.

When the user clicks submit you would iterate your map looking for a key equal to the user's form responses on all N answers. With the index value found you would then get the image and link on another collection, perhaps an array.

This solution is simple but, on the other side, you'll need to have on the map every possible combination. With 10 questions in a form that would be 2 to the power of 10 = 1024 map entries.

To deal with this handicap you could use a third value, besides true and false, on your map to denote either answer. So when iterating the map, you would stop when the answers had the same value or the value on the map were the third value (e.g. null). That way you can possibily have fewer map entries, depending on your specific need.